# A manga about two girls being summoned to another world and mistaken identity

Tags: plus-alpha-no-tachiichi

I have read the first chapter of this manga in 2014. There was only 1 chapter of the manga when I read.

The main heroine considered herself an average girl, and she had a female friend whom she considered a very beautiful girl and the perfect heroine. However, when the MC met her, she saw that her friend was being sucked into a portal.

When they woke up, it seemed that the summoner was supposed to summon the Goddess of Creation (I think). In the confusion, the beautiful girl was mistaken as the Goddess (since the MC was average), but the MC found out that she herself was actually the Goddess. So the MC's plan was just to support her friend to play as the Goddess, while the MC herself made miracle behind her back...

Answer (score 7):

I'm quite sure it is [**+α no Tachi Ichi**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=99920)

Your description of the manga is extremely similar to the synopsis from mangaupdates:

> Satoki Houma is an imaginative girl who enjoys shoujo manga. She has long comes to terms with the fact she will never be the type of girl that is the heroine of a manga — purely because she isn’t pretty, and she has decided she prefers to watch events unfold rather that get involved in any case. However, in the perfect shoujo manga twist, one day she gets dragged to an alternate world where the people have summoned a Holy Maiden to save them…!
>
> Except so did her classmate, Haruka Toudou, who fits the exact model of a Shoujo Protagonist. Naturally, Satoki is overlooked for Haruka… except it’s not Haruka who has the powers of the Holy Maiden they wished for. What will Satoki do!?

<sup>By the way, I easily found the manga by going through the [list of series tagged with *Transported to Another World*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?category=Transported+to+Another+World&orderby=year) on mangaupdates.</sup>

Comment: We will need [Scouters](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Scouter) attuned to people's search-fu (previously Google-fu) power levels soon.

Comment: @Mindwin It's only going to ever show Over 9000, so what's the point :p

Comment: @StorymasterQ more like near zero for these lazy types.